# BCP What should the row terminator be for this text file?

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, bcp

Okay so, I'm trying to insert a large text file into a table using bcp. The table is supposed to have 95 columns, and the last column should be a SourceCheckSum which is like `|...|-1|`.

The text file has over 200,000,000 rows and abruptly stops at the last row that has `|...|-1|` at the end.

However I need it to NOT stop there, but continue! Sometimes the file doesn't just end in `|-1|` but something like `|...|-1|871447296`

```
99B-9009-8||99B90098|1|||||MH| ||13749|||ALTAMONT PASS|RD||13749 ALTAMONT PASS RD|LIVERMORE|CA|94550||||||||||| |||64-005||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||339847213|N||||N|||||||||||0|332443|-1|
027D604E-2AD5-E511-80C1-3863BB43AC67|9355733|06001|CA|ALAMEDA||072012|20|BKF|99B-9009-9||99B90099|1|||||MH| |P|2234|||LAUGHLIN|RD||2234 LAUGHLIN RD|LIVERMORE|CA|94551|8749|||||||||| |||64-001||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||339847214|Y|||R008|Y|37.732900|-121.714000|060014511.011017||||||||0|332443|-1|
1C9D952A-45D5-E511-80C1-3863BB43AC67|8904539|06001|CA|ALAMEDA|2015-07-01|072015|23|BKF|1-1111-10||1111110|1|001 -1111-010||A||| |P|311|||OAK|ST||311 OAK ST|OAKLAND|CA|94607|4602||||||||5377.2400|2014| |||17-022|A      |||||SIERRA AT JACK LONDON SQUARE|||105   ||||||||||||||||1|||||||1791318416|Y|APT|105|C010|Y|37.794136|-122.266898|060014033.001030||||||||0|361491|-1|-902735596
1D9D952A-45D5-E511-80C1-3863BB43AC67|8904540|06001|CA|ALAMEDA|2015-07-01|072015|23|BKF|1-1111-11||1111111|1|001 -1111-011||A||| ||311|||OAK|ST||311 OAK ST|OAKLAND|CA|94607|4602||||||||3908.9400|2014| |||17-022|A      |||||SIERRA AT JACK LONDON SQUARE|||106   ||||||||||||||||1|||||||1791318417|Y|APT|106|C010|Y|37.794136|-122.266898|060014033.001030||||||||0|361491|-1|871447296
```

I have checked the schema when I received the dataset and they say that SourceCheckSum should be the last column. My question is there a way I can pass in a terminator of the form `'*\n'`?

edit:

I've tried making the last column a varchar to absorb the last column, but it still ends abruptly at the same place for some reason.

Comment: You have described the file, but you haven't told us what you are trying to do with the file.

Comment: I'm trying to insert a large text file into a table using bcp.

Comment: Maybe an overflow? Have you tried to limit the number of rows to export?

Comment: Yes. Btw I’m inserting not exporting. I tried importing on a table of size 10 and it stops inserting when it sees those random numbers at the end